# How to click on an element generated by javascript with Watir?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, watir

I'm developing an jsf based application using a library called primefaces.
Primefaces generates a web page containing javascript functions that are generating some buttons. Buttons are not visible in the source code of the page (like < button>...< /button>, and so Watir can't click on these to test something.

My question is : is it possible to recover the id or class of button generated by a javascript function with Watir ?

Thanks

Comment: If they are generated via javascript, they will not appear in the source. However, if you use `puts browser.html` you should see them.

Comment: Thanks to you, i've discovered that the delay needed to load the page wasn't long enough : the web page where i was looking for the button wasn't the good one. So I had a sleep instruction to let the browser load the good page and that works fine now. Thanks !

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [wait methods in Watir](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) rather than using sleeps.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, using `sleep` is [not recommended](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+to+wait+with+Watir#HowtowaitwithWatir-2ObjectsthatdependonJavascripttoshowup).  Depending on the amount of time the browser & JavaScript code takes to perform its action, you could run into race conditions and end up with tests that only work *sometimes*.

> If you're considering using sleep, use wait_until instead. It will make your test code more resilient to timing issues in those cases where you really need to use it.

As @JustinKo recommended, you should probably be using Watir's [wait methods](http://watirwebdriver.com/waiting/) to wait until the element is displayed on the page.

In your case, you'd want to try something like these examples:

```
# Assuming your browser object is named: $b
#Ex: $b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
$b.button(:id => 'my_button').wait_until_present
Watir::Waiter::wait_until { $b.button(:id => 'my_button').visible? }
```

If you are having trouble finding the element on the page, you might want to look a the source code in FireBug or the Developer Tools console in Chrome (`Shift+Ctrl+I`).  Try to find some identifying attribute for that button, or a container element with an `id`, `class`, `name` or some other identifying attribute.

However, at this time I'm not sure that there is a way to detect whether an element was generated or added to the DOM by JavaScript.